# ExpandableListView with a header in extended LinearLayout: NullPointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, expandablelistview

I have defined a simple custom `View` by extending `LinearLayout`. The crux is that it contains an `ExpandableListView` with a header view added:

```
public class MyView extends LinearLayout {
private View mHeaderView;
private ExpandableListView mListView;

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public MyView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    init(context);
}

@SuppressWarnings("UnusedDeclaration")
public MyView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    init(context);
}

private void init(Context context) {
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    //Inflate custom view into LinearLayout
    inflater.inflate(
            R.layout.merge_myview, this);

    //Inflate header with no parent so we can set it as the ListView header in onFinishInflate()
    mHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_bundles_list, null);
}

@Override
protected void onFinishInflate() {
    super.onFinishInflate();

    mListView = (ExpandableListView) (findViewById(R.id.lv_expandable));

    Log.d("MyView", "Almost done...");

    //Commenting out this line makes it work
    mListView.addHeaderView(mHeaderView, null, false);
}
}
```

Here's `merge_myview.xml`:

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/lv_expandable"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />    
</merge>
```

Here's the header:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#EFEEFF"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:minHeight="96dp"
        android:onClick="openPane"
        android:paddingBottom="24dp"
        android:paddingTop="24dp"
        android:text="HELLO!"
        android:textColor="#333333"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:textSize="48sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

With a plain `onCreate` in my activity:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myview);
}
```

Where `activity_myview.xml` contains only my custom view:

```
<com.example.app.MyView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"/>
```

However, when I run this app, I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException   at
 android.widget.ListView.clearRecycledState(ListView.java:507)   at
 android.widget.ListView.resetList(ListView.java:493)   at
 android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1431)   at
 android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1147)   at
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)   at
 android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1252)   at
 android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1128)   at
 android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1045)   at
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)   at
 android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)   at
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)   at
 android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1252)   at
 android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1128)   at 
 android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1045)   at
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)   at
 android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1252)   at
 android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1128)   at
 android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1045)   at
 android.view.View.layout(View.java:7035)
```

I suppose this is a bug that was fixed somewhere between Android 2.3.7 and 4.1.1, because I only get the error when testing with the former. <s>I can't find it in the [bug tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list?can=1&q=expandablelistview&colspec=ID+Type+Status+Owner+Summary+Stars&cells=tiles), though.</s>  So why does this error occur? And is there any workaround?

---

## EDIT

I think [this](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=3391&can=1&q=expandablelistview%20header&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars) is the bug, fixed in June 2013.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try not using a merge.

```
private void init(Context context) {
    setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);
    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

    inflater.inflate(R.layout.expandablelistview, this, true);
    inflater.inflate(R.layout.textview, this, true);
    mHeaderView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.header_bundles_list, null);
}
```

`expandablelistview.xml`

```
<ExpandableListView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lv_expandable"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffd467"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

`textview.xml`

```
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/textview"
    android:text="HELLO"
    android:background="#AA4242"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

Example `onCreate()`:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_myview);
    MyView myView = (MyView) findViewById(R.id.myview);

    //Set up adapter
    int groupnum=2;
    int childnum=3;
    List<Map<String, String>> groupData=new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(groupnum);
    List<List<Map<String,String>>> childData=new ArrayList<List<Map<String, String>>>(groupnum);
    for(int i=0;i<groupnum;i++){
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
        map.put("title","I'm a group");
        groupData.add(map);

        List<Map<String, String>> thisChildData = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(childnum);
        for(int j=0;j<childnum;j++){
        HashMap<String, String> childmap = new HashMap<String, String>(1);
            childmap .put("title","I'm a child");
            thisChildData.add(childmap );
        }
        childData.add(thisChildData);
    }

    ExpandableListAdapter adapter=new SimpleExpandableListAdapter(
            this,
            groupData,
            android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,
            new String[] {"title"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1},
            childData,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] {"title"},
            new int[] {android.R.id.text1}
    );

    //Set adapter
    myView.mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

replace

```
mListView = (ExpandableListView) (findViewById(R.id.lv_expandable));
```

with

```
mListView = (ExpandableListView) (mHeaderView.findViewById(R.id.lv_expandable));
```

Comment: Uh, that doesn't really make sense if `mHeaderView` is a header of the `ExpandableListView`..? Are you sure?